# Best way to run a recurring task in windows as a non-admin user?

Tags: c#, windows

I was under the impression that Scheduled Tasks would be the best way to run a C# 'sync' service (makes REST requests and writes to MySQL database) that runs every half hour. However, it seems like in Windows 10, I would need to tweak the rights of a non-admin user (the 'run as batch' rights) in order to make this happen (something which isn't the case in earlier versions of windows?). On the other hand, if I were to schedule the task as an administrator, the non-admin can't even see the task, let alone get last run time and result. Thus, no way for non-admin user to see if the task exists or has run successfully other than writing results to a log or something.

I'm thinking I might just go back to using timers in an application that is constantly running. Is there a more 'efficient' way?

Comment: previous windows did it just silently changed it - you could write a service

Comment: Wouldn't this be suited for SuperUser SE?

Comment: Why would you require admin rights to essentially make a http request to the Internet and write to a DB?

Comment: @MickyD Windows 10 apparently requires me to have admin rights (in order to give the user the 'log on as batch job' rights) to run a scheduled task as a non-admin user--although I may be mistaken about that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get too confused here. Tasks have both an owner, and a user they run as. By default only the owner of a job and admins can see/execute the job. The owner defaults to being the user who created the job.

You an admin can manually grant a non-admin user the needed right using local group policy. This policy is accessible by opening **Local Security Policy**. In the **Local Security Policy** window, click **Local Policy**, **User Rights Assignment**, and then **Logon as batch** job. You can add the user here, unless a higher level of group policy prevents this.

Alternatively, you can have the task run as "NT Authority\Local Service" which is a non-admin account, which implicitly has the needed priveledge. You must set this up as an admin. Of course that means the admin will own the job.

Regular users can be given access to see/execute the job. To do this the admin should locate the task on disk (it will be found in the `C:\windows\system32\tasks` directory), and use the security tab to grant "Read & Execute" to "Users" or to specific users as desired.

Microsoft actually does that with some of their tasks by default, even if the task runs with SYSTEM permissions (although obviously they have the installer change the Task File's security, rather than doing it by hand).

Comment: `Now at this point, the user should have the needed right.` This doesn't seem to be the case. I just get an error that the user doesn't have that right.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin: Damn. It looks like that information in the microsoft documentation is out of date. Only the windows 2003 era "Add Scheduled Task Wizard" seems to grant the priveldge automatically. I'll update by answer.